# createdb: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, postgresql

I just built/installed Postgresql on my Ubuntu machine, and I am having trouble getting it to actually run, I keep getting the error.

I set up the server to run and output a logfile (exactly as in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/installation.html)), it appears to work fine (running as 'su - postgres' who owns the pgsql directory):

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/postmaster -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &
[1] 2200
```

But then, I try to create a db, and I get this error:

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb test
-su: usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb: No such file or directory
[1]+  Exit 2                  /usr/local/pgsql/bin/postmaster -D /usr/local/pgsql/data > logfile 2>&1
```

Any ideas of what I am missing?  I have done this before - I am just confused right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uhm... you're missing a / at the start.

The bash prompt says you're $home, and you're running createdb without beginning with /, so it's looking for $home/usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb